# Inequality regarding the logarithm

Tags: inequality

I have found the inequality
$$
x\leq cy+\frac{1}{\log(c)}(x-y)\log(x/y),
$$
for all $x,y>0$ and $c>1$. Why is this inequality true?

Comment: The paper you reference says the result is here: R. J. Di Perna, P. L. Lions On the Cauchy problem for Boltzmann equations: Global
existence and weak stability. Annals of Mathematics, 130 (1989) pp. 321–366.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, see that the inequality is equivalent to the following:
$$
1\leq cy+\frac{1}{\log(c)}(1-y)\log(1/y).
$$
If $cy\geq 1$, the result is trivial. Let's assume otherwise $cy<1$ which implies $y<1$. After rearranging terms, we get:
$$
\frac{1-cy}{1-y}\log c\leq \log(1/y).
$$
Using Jensen inequality we can see that:
$$
\frac{1-cy}{1-y}\log c+ \frac{cy-y}{1-y}\log 1 
\leq \log(
\frac{c-c^2y+cy-y}{1-y}).
$$
Now it is only a matter of algebraic manipulation to see that:
$$
\frac{c-c^2y+cy-y}{1-y}\leq\frac{1}y,
$$
which is equivalent to:
$$
(c^2-c+1)y^2-(c+1)y+1\geq 0.
$$
It can be seen that $\Delta=-3(c-1)^2<0$ and $c^2-c+1>0$ and so the result follows.

Comment: How is the inequality equivalent to that?

Comment: Divide two sides by $x$ and then take $\frac yx$ as new variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Jstor account,
the paper where this is proved
is here:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971423?seq=3#page_scan_tab_contents

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Take $c=2, x=2, y=1$. Then the RHS is
$$2\times 1 + \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)(2-1) \ln\left(\frac{2}{1}\right) < 2
$$
and not $\ge 2.$

Comment: Ooops I wrote the inequality wrong... Please, take a look at it now. I found the inequality in this paper (equation (10)) Wow, this is surprising :-). I found the equation in this paper (equation 10): http://www.uni-graz.at/~fellnerk/preprints/DFIFIP.pdf